# Generate website content from external server?

Tags: php, server

So here is the problem.  I want to be able to install a file(or files) on another server A, but I want the page content to be generated by connecting to server B based on some passed parameters.

Here is the example.

So, I install the files on server A at the following location:

www.serverA.com/folder1/myfile.php

If necessary we can also put up other files in subfolders to make it work.

The user is then able to go to the following URL:

www.serverA.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/

And what the file does is it will get the text in /folder2/ and /folder3/ (this will probably require a small bit of code in an .htaccess file in /folder1/) and sends it to a specified URL on serverB.  Server B then processes the information, and sends it back to Server A where the processed information is shown to the users.

For this simple proof of concept, all I need is for the programmer to implement the following:

www.serverA.com/test/3/4/

This page should send the 3 and 4 to server 4, and send back the sum (7) and multiple (12) back to SERVER A to show on the screen.  To test it I should be able to change the numbers in the URL and the sum and multiple should come back correctly.

I do not want to use CURL (as it keeps giving 403 errors on my servers and I don't have access to php.ini) or file_get_contents as I have read it is not a best practice.  I am open to any other options that work.

The long-term idea is to create an app that people can install on their websites that will generate content for them based on parameters they send my server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to recreate the functionality similar to existing `RSS` feed?

Comment: wow! use dynamic urls with your desired values-. its possible but alot of arguments will be done.

Comment: To be more specific I have a number of websites, but I want to create a way to generate pages on many of them (non-spam) based on some information in the server on the main server and based on the URL that the user enters.

Answer (score 0):

Would an IFrame work? A document on IFrames can be seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I should have mentioned that I want the page that is generatd to be readable/indexable by Google and other crawlers.  An Iframe would just show a blank page.

Comment: you can use an iframe and stuff the website with information. so users can use the iframe but google will get the title and info from the <head>